# ¿"Toggle" en castellano?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, informática

Con frecuencia veo aplicaciones informáticas en las que hay un botoncito "toggle" para indicar "activar/desactivar" algo.

<sub>[Parte técnica] Por ejemplo, en Git podemos usarlo para indicar si queremos que los comentarios aparezcan (o no) cuando se revisa un código.</sub>

Veo que la traducción de tal palabra es "alternar", "conmutar", "turnar" como verbo o "interruptor", "conmutador" como nombre. Sin embargo, ninguna de ellas me acaba de convencer y no sé si la gente entendería su funcionalidad en una aplicación en castellano que usara esta terminología.

¿Qué os parece? ¿Se os ocurre alguna palabra que encaje mejor con este concepto?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Analizando dos definiciones:

1. [Linguee](http://www.linguee.es/ingles-espanol/traduccion/toggle.html):

   - como verbo: alternar, cambiar
   - como sustantivo: conmutación
2. [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=toggle):

   - como verbo: alternar, conmutar, turnar

Y analizando —en la primera de las anteriores (Linguee)— algunos de los ejemplos traducidos (tomados de páginas con versiones en ambos idiomas):

1. > A dedicated mode
   >   button let you quickly toggle between photos and clocks. <sup>[[1]](http://www.philips.co.uk/c/digital-photo/17.8-cm-7-inch-spf2307_10/prd/)</sup>
   >   Un botón de modo específico
   >   que te permite alternar rápidamente entre las fotos y el reloj. <sup>[[2]](http://www.philips.es/c/fotografia-digital/17.8-cm-7-pulgada-spf2307_10/prd/)</sup>
2. > A toggle control that defines the territory as inactive. <sup>[[3]](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_sbo88/helpdata/en/45/06b9737d720487e10000000a155369/content.htm)</sup>
   >   Un control de conmutación que define el territorio como inactivo. <sup>[[4]](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_sbo88/helpdata/es/45/06b9737d720487e10000000a155369/content.htm)</sup>

Y considerando la experiencia que tengo desarrollando software en ambos idiomas, creo sinceramente que las mejores traducciones son:

- como verbo: alternar
- como sustantivo: conmutación (aunque no tan claro).

Lo más recomendable sería evitar su uso (en tanto sustantivo) con una sola palabra, y en estos casos preferir alguna frase de reemplazo, tal como el ejemplo que tú das de Git.

Comment: También se podría traducir como interruptor, conmutador o selector, como sustantivos.

Answer (score 1):

Yo me quedaria con Permutar o Trocar. Literalmente significan lo que entendemos por Toggle. Segun el objetivo, alternar seria adecuado.

Es bueno usar palabras poco usadas comunmente para recordar mejor los nombres de funciones y variables. Se evitan parecidos y repeticiones con funcionalidades muy similares.